# Writing gt table to pdf using pdf()

Tags: r, pdf, gt

I'm trying to write a gt table to pdf using the pdf() function with the following code.
This works very well with ggplots, but for some reason not with gt.
The reason for using the pdf() function is that I'm looking to create a single pdf document with multiple plots and tables.

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

islands_tbl <- 
  tibble(
    name = names(islands),
    size = islands
  ) %>%
  arrange(desc(size)) %>%
  slice(1:10)


pdf()
plot(x = 1:10,  y = 1:10)
plot(x = 1:10,  y = 11:20)
gt(islands_tbl) %>% print
dev.off()
```

Comment: From its https://gt.rstudio.com/, *"gt supports the HTML, LaTeX, and RTF output formats"*, it does not output directly to a graphics format that can be easily combined with other plots. What you want is best done in [R markdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) (and it is relatively trivial).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think gt::gtsave function is what you are looking for.

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

islands_tbl <- 
  tibble(
    name = names(islands),
    size = islands
  ) %>%
  arrange(desc(size)) %>%
  slice(1:10)


gt(islands_tbl) %>% 
gtsave('islands.pdf')
```

If you need a complete pdf document including table and previous plots as well, I should use an Rmarkdown file with output:pdf_document

Comment: Thanks - the goal was to have it in a single pdf doc. R markdown seems to be the only solution so far . Maybe it’s just me but I never get very far with Rmarkdown as pretty soon you hit some limitation of the tool. I also don’t like that it requires a seperate R environment.